# Retrieve block number from geth and display it on my webpage

Tags: web3js, dapps

I am running geth using this command:

```
geth -testnet --syncmode light console
```

and I am trying to retrieve the block number from geth and display it on my web app. In geth when I type:

```
eth.blockNumber
```

I get the block number to display. How can I get my web app to show the block number when the page loads?

I thought it would be something like this but its not working:

```
   web3.eth.getBlockNumber(function(err, num) 
      { if (err === null)  {   
           console.log(num);
      }});
```

Comment: how are you connecting your web3 to the blockchain?
why you dont use await instead of a callback function

Comment: @MajdTL I am connecting with Metamask. I wanted to get the block number from geth without turning on MetaMask.

Comment: please post the code u used to init web, that could be a part of the  answer